# How to find out if a website is hosted in IIS, apache or any other server

Tags: iis, webserver

How to find out if a website is hosted in IIS, apache or any other server. Only information available with me is the page url. I need to create a proposal for the enhancement of the website but would like to get as much info before going forward. from the url i can see .aspx extension and can assume it is asp.net in IIS?

http://check-host.net/ similar websites i checked but no info on the server.

Comment: Did you consider asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to send an http HEAD request.

```
curl -I url
```

will request server information

telnet dnsname www
   HEAD HTTP/1.0

can do the same.  For example

```
telnet google.com www
```

then type

```
HEAD HTTP/1.0
```

and a return.  Look to the Server: field that comes back in the response. The www at the end of the telnet command requests a connect to port 80, not the normal port 23.  curl -I is likely easier.  Even though some servers will respond with Bad Request, perhaps because they support HTTP/1.1, the HEAD response will still contain the Server: field.  Of course, like all things internet, the response may be a compatibility response, or perhaps an outright lie, but most server software doesn't lie, it is not really in its best interest to do so.

Comment: tried telnet but "connect failed". my url is actually a subdomain. may be it is because i m trying from my office where there are many firewalls enabled. curl is to run from cmd prompt? its not "recognized"

Comment: any websites which gives the details?

Comment: Did you try  `telnet google.com www` ?  You don't want to connect to port 23, but port 80 the "www" at the end is a parameter to telnet.  Don't add any http colon slash slash part either.  Again, `curl -I url` will likely be easier.  (Capital eye, as in Info), and yes `curl` is a command name.  You may need to install it.   If you can get the IP address of the server, then telnet ip www should work as well, without need of DNS lookups.  If you can browse to it, you aren't blocked by firewalls.

Comment: In terms of details, this is simply an HTTP HEAD request.  Google http head.  RFC 2616, by Tim Berners-Lee and friends.

Comment: connection to google itself failed when tried telnet with www. it should be some office traffic restrictions i suppose.